# Siri full sentence order, like sending message via whatsApp

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have been searching for days about Siri integration with an IOS app.
I know about the Siri shortcuts/intents etc.

How do I have Siri take a full sentence such as "Text John I'm on my way" or "Text John via WhatsApp I'm on my way"

Is this something exclusive to Apple apps, is it limited to messaging only or are there other ways to integrate with Siri?

I'm not looking to integrate messaging app, but i'm looking to integrate the full sentence with parameters order/question.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides [SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit) which gives your application the ability to requests that originate from Siri.

You can look at the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sirikit/overview/domains-and-intents/) to learn more about designing an interface to interact with Siri.

Do some searcing on SiriKit examples. There are quite a few sources that show how do to an integration with your app.

If you are looking for information about speech recognition within your app, then you may want to look at the Apple [Speech Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech)

This framework gives you lower level voice recognition and parsing capabilities and may have the flexibility you need.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Messaging is not specific to Apple apps.

You can make your application to behave similar to Message app. You need to implement the app extension specific to message intent and add resolve param methods to the handler to handle user input.

Reference for Messaging with SiriKit

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/messaging?changes=latest_minor
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/insendmessageintent

Sample source - https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_10_Example_SiriKit_Messaging_Extension
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/extending-your-ios-app-with-sirikit-fd1a7ef12ba6